# Running 32-bit application on CUDA

Tags: cuda

I read on the CUDA toolkit documentation (11.3.0) that "Deployment and execution of CUDA applications on x86_32 is still supported, but is limited to use with GeForce GPUs."

This looks in conflict with the fact that I was able to run a 32-bit app on my Tesla T4. (I verified that the code was actually running on the GPU and the app was 32-bit).

Have I misinterpreted the documentation? Why am I able to run 32-bit apps on a Tesla GPU?

(I'm running Visual studio 2017 on Windows 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of what is *supported*.

Other things may work, or they may not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "things" may not work? Are you talking about libraries such as cuBLAS or thrust, or also the runtime API?

Comment: Not really.  Part of "not supported" means "not tested". You are working in an unsupported setting.  In addition, if you found problems that were unique to that setting, it is unlikely that NVIDIA would attempt to fix those, as that setting is not supported.